# Auto insert cell to Jupyter Notebook after running a cell in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am unable to automatically insert a cell after running my cell which is annoying as it breaks workflow on Jupyter Notebooks on Visual Studio Code. Can someone suggest a good extension or a hidden setting in vscode to enable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Shift+Enter shortcut to run the current cell and insert a new cell below. Please file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter if this is currently not working as expected for you.